# What to use for basic video playback and editing in .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, video, directshow, ms-media-foundation

What is the best solution for building video playback with basic real-time editing features into per-existing .NET application? 
I have a legacy .NET application, running on Windows 7+ systems. I need to build a video player that would be able to rearrange segments of video and seamlessly play a few video files one after another. Basically a simple video editing instrument. What is the best tool or framework available for the task at the moment?

I used to work with DirectShow in the past, thought about using that but pretty much the entire [DirectShow Editing Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375458(v=vs.85).aspx) section is marked as not supported which is not encouraging to say the least. And I don't see any way to use MediaFoundation with a .NET based shell.

Are there any reasonable options for work with media content available for .NET based applications at all?

Comment: Video editing could be implemented using Media Foundation, by using IMFSourceReader and IMFSinkWriter for instance. You can check MFCopy media foundation sample. It has basic video trimming functionality implemented: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnode/